# Is there a way of swiping between single spaces on a multi-monitor setup?

Tags: display, spaces, multi-touch

In Lion, being able to swipe between desktops with the trackpad is great. However since adding another monitor to my setup, what I really want to be able to do is swipe desktops across monitors. E.g. if I have the following setup:

```
Desktop 1 | Desktop 2 | XCode | Chrome
```

Instead of swiping left from Desktop 1 replacing the contents of both screens, Desktop 1 is displayed on the left hand monitor and Desktop 2 on the right. Swiping left moves Desktop 2 to the left hand monitor, and full screen Xcode to the right hand monitor. This would be especially useful as XCode/Chrome etc. just blank out the second monitor when in fullscreen mode, which is really annoying!

Is there an app or setting that can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, the multi monitor support on Lion is ridiculously lacking, especially given Apple jumping up and down about how amazing Thunderbolts (and the displays) are.

If you want to use more than one screen, you are pretty much unable to use FullScreen. (without making the secondary screen useless)

Comment: How irritating. I just made the switch from Snow Leopard to Lion and I must admit it's worse in a lot of ways that matter to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Better Touch Tool](http://blog.boastr.net/). I think it can not exactly do what you want, but you can define gestures, that let you move a window from one screen on an other.

Comment: wrong question, he is not looking to move windows at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just maximize the two applications you want, and put both apps into their own screen within the same space. Yeah, it's not "full screen" but it's virtually the same idea and lets you swipe through panes of apps, and lets you use both screens at once.